# Unable to connect to check.torproject.org

Tags: torcheck

Even when I'm not using Tor or any proxy, I can't connect check.torproject.org. The circular icon would turn and turn in the tab for several minutes, then the message below. Am I the only one with this problem? Meanwhile, I am able to connect to other sites without any problems. Using Tor or just a normal browser. Can I trust that I am using Tor even when unable to verify via check.torproject.org?

*Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at check.torproject.org.

```
   The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.

   If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer’s network connection.

   If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Tor Browser is permitted to access the Web.*
```

Answer (score 2):

https://check.torproject.org/ may be down temporarily due to a long list of reasons, ranging from DDoS attacks to a simple planned maintenance.

Disable DNS in your network settings and try to visit a Web site in .onion zone. If you can do that, you're using Tor.